# Unicode issue with strftime on Windows jRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, jruby, strftime

I have a date/time format:

```
format = '%Y年%b%d日 %H:%M'
```

calling `Time#strftime(format)` (e.g. `Time.now.strftime(format)` produces:

```
> Time.now.strftime(format)
=> "2013?Jun20? 11:56"
```

I'm using jruby 1.7.2 (1.9.3p327) on Windows. Is there a way to make `strftime` Unicode-compatible?

**Update**

Windows console hasn't been very accommodating for Unicode, when I output just format, I get:

```
> I18n.t :'time.formats.long'
=> "%YÕ╣┤%b%dµùÑ %H:%M"
```

but at least it's something. It's trying to show Unicode characters, whereas `strftime` just ignores it:

```
> I18n.t(:'time.formats.long').encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
> Time.now.strftime("").encoding
=> #<Encoding:Windows-1252>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not your console that is not unicode compatible? What happens if you actually try to print out those Hanzi characters?

Comment: Updated the question with an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's a **readline** (shipped with JRuby) issue, a simple fix is start irb with option `--noreadline` (Or add `IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = false` in your ~/.irbrc).

   ```sh
   C:\ConEmu>jirb
   irb(main):001:0> format = '%Y年%b%d日 %H:%M'
   => "%Y?b%d?%H:%M"                # Readline cannot handle GBK input here
   irb(main):002:0> exit

   C:\ConEmu>jirb --noreadline
   irb(main):001:0> format = '%Y年%b%d日 %H:%M'
   => "%Y年%b%d日 %H:%M"             # without Readline, it works
   irb(main):002:0> format.encoding
   => #<Encoding:GBK>
   irb(main):003:0> Time.now.strftime(format)
   => "2013??Jun20?? 23:20"         # strftime cannot process GBK input here
   ```
2. `strftime` won't function well with a GBK encoded string. So encode the parameter to UTF-8 before passing it to `strftime`. BTW, it's very strange behavior that strftime returns GBK encoded string regardless of `Encoding.default_internal`!

   ```sh
   C:\ConEmu>jirb --noreadline
   irb(main):001:0> format = '%Y年%b%d日 %H:%M'
   => "%Y年%b%d日 %H:%M"
   irb(main):002:0> Time.now.strftime(format.encode('utf-8'))
   => "2013年Jun20日 23:32"

   irb(main):003:0> Time.now.strftime(format.encode('utf-8')).encoding
   => #<Encoding:GBK>
   irb(main):004:0> Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
   => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
   irb(main):005:0> Time.now.strftime(format.encode('utf-8')).encoding
   => #<Encoding:GBK>
   ```

I don't have Rails environment under JRuby, so I cannot help with the I18n encoding issue.

Readline is provided as JVM bytecode class files, as a result, you don't have easy way patching the library. So it is with `strftime`.

**It's my first taste on JRuby** (I was interested in the Encoding problem about Ruby), **but I don't think I will pick it up ever again**.

If you are finding some programming languages on JVM, you can take a look at Scala. It's more consistent, productive and creative, and (the most important compared to JRuby) less bug-prone in libraries.

Or if you are interested in Ruby, try [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) on Windows, or install [RVM](http://rvm.io) under Linux on a virtual machine. I'm sure you will find less trouble compared with JRuby, at least less Encoding trouble.

Comment: Now that's a very extensive answer to a problem. Thank you very much! Unfortunately, at the time I wasn't able to switch to *nix. Of course switching to *nix environment fixes most of issues with encoding. :)